# How do I view the "Created by" and other default columns?

Tags: list

In the settings for my list, I can see the default Created By, Modified By, etc columns. But when I just view the list on my Sharepoint site, I can't see those. How do I make them visible, just like all the other columns?

Answer (score 0):

While viewing the list, click on the down arrow next to any individual column, and find "Show/hide columns".

[image]

This is confusing because that arrow is next to each individual column header, making it look like those are just the settings for those individual columns, as opposed to *all* columns including hidden ones. But there it is.